# How to define Model

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to define a class which returns vlaues for 3 dropdown.

Like my class should return 3 list which are dependent.

Like 1st dropdown is a field dropdown second is operator dropdown(=,#,>,<) 3rd is the corresponding value for the first dropdown.
How do i define a model

Comment: If you bother only writing webapi, you can provide may be three separate actions (returning same model if the properties are same or return different models if the properties different) and let the UI handle how to provide cascading dropdown and fetch the value based on dropdown value by calling your webapi action methods.

Comment: Can you show me with an example. If i choose Country from my first dropdown my 2nd dropdown will have (equal to and not equal to ) values and 3rd will have all the country names like (india, USA etc). If i  choose city then third one should populate all cities. Can you show me with an example . Am just learning web api

Comment: Please search for Cascading dropdown example and you should see plenty online. One such example is [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Cascading-DropDown-in-MVC4-dba6022f)